# Sending user edit form to user profile

Tags: 7, users, forms

I'm trying to send user edit page to the user profile page (/user), so I can get user profile informations and user edit form on the same page.

```
function hook_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
  $vars['form'] = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account);
}
```

Then in user-profile.tpl.php I have the following :

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_address']); ?>
<?php // Print necessary validation fields and remove others
      unset($form['field_user_society_id']);
      unset($form['field_user_locations']);
      unset($form['locale']);
      unset($form['account']);
      print drupal_render($form);
 ?>
```

It works well, I have my form, the datas are coming into it but when saving it, even if I get status message "Changes have been saved" actually no datas are saved.

I tried to put `module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');`in a hook_init() and in a form_alter, but no way to get the form datas saved.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could it be because 'account' is being removed?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgottent some infos. $account is just a var for user_load.

Comment: You could try [`hook_url_inbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7.x) and [`hook_url_outbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x) for 'faking' front-end paths. It would allow you to serve the form under a different url. But I am not sure if it overrides `hook_menu`. Otherwise you would have to use `hook_menu_alter` to remove the `user` path, but then you will probably run into weird issues where `user/login` and `user/logout` are no longer available.

Comment: Actually my users get logged through a oauth2 api. What I need is to get the user profile information and the user edit form on the same page. So It's not about a url problem :). Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Aporie, that is quite an important detail :) I assumed you wanted to replace the profile information entirely. Could you edit it into the question?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was quite simple.

I just needed to remove the call to `$form['field_user_address']`

```
//<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_address']); ?>
<?php // Print necessary validation fields and remove others
      unset($form['field_user_society_id']);
      unset($form['field_user_locations']);
      unset($form['locale']);
      unset($form['account']);
      print drupal_render($form);
 ?>
```